# Tkinter how to prevent users entering strings into spin box

Tags: python, tkinter

I need the user to enter an integer number into my program. They shouldn't be able to enter strings/floats. If the user hasn't entered an integer and clicks the button I would like an error message to pop up similar to the one you get if your username/password is incorrect when logging into something.

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.iv = IntVar()
        self.sb = Spinbox(parent, from_=0, to=10, textvariable = self.iv)
        self.sb.pack()
        self.b1 = Button(parent, text="Confirm")
        self.b1.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
GUI = GUI(root)
root.title("Example")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try converting the text to an integer within a try/except block, then if it runs the except empty the box

Comment: Could you use `values=range(11)` when creating your Spinbox.

Comment: @SolarFactories with python 3, you need to convert the `range` into a `list`: `values=list(range(11))`.

Answer (score 3):

The spinbox supports input validation in exactly the same way as the Entry widget. You can set up a `validatecommand` that will only allow digits to be entered.

For example:

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        # add validation to the spinbox
        vcmd = (parent.register(self.validate_spinbox), '%P')
        self.sb.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)

    def validate_spinbox(self, new_value):
        # Returning True allows the edit to happen, False prevents it.
        return new_value.isdigit()
```

For more information on input validation see [Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter/4140988#4140988)

Answer (score 3):

You may use the option state = 'readonly'. This option applies to Spinbox and Combobox also. With this option setted the user can only choose from the values you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code corresponding to Splinxyy suggestion:
convert the spinbox content with `int()` inside a try/except block

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.iv = IntVar()
        self.sb = Spinbox(parent, from_=0, to=10, textvariable = self.iv)
        self.sb.pack()
        self.b1 = Button(parent, text="Confirm", command=self.validate)
        self.b1.pack()

    def validate(self):
        nb = self.sb.get()
        try:
            nb = int(nb)
            # do something with the number
            print(nb)
        except Exception:
            showerror('Error', 'Invalid content')


root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
GUI = GUI(root)
root.title("Example")
root.mainloop()
```